# How can I Search for a node's contents in a Generic Linked List with a String Input?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to return all node contents that match a given String input. What I am trying to do is essentially a very simple search engine, where the user is able to type in a String and the program returns all characteristically similar contents it can find in the linked list. The linked list itself is built from a file, formatted as

<<Game’s Name 0>>\t<<Game’s Console 0>>\n

<<Game’s Name 1>>\t<<Game’s Console 1>>\n

where the lines are delimited with a \n and the game and its corresponding console are delimited with a \t.

My current methodology follows searching the linked list with a while loop, assigning a temporary value to the head and reassigning it to it's link as it goes down the list. Once the loop finds contents within a node that matches the current input, it stops the loop and returns the data found in the node. I have yet to try if this could be done with a for loop, as the while loop more than likely would not know when to continue once it has found a match. I am also unsure if the while loop argument is the most efficient one to use, as my understanding of it is very minimal. I believe !temp.equals(query) is stating "temp does not equal query," but I have a feeling that this could be done in a more efficient manner.

This is what I have so far, I will provide the entire Generic linked list class for the sake of context, but the method I am questioning is the very last one, found at line 126.

My explicitly stated question is how can I search through a linked list's contents and return those contents through the console.

```java
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GenLL<T>
{
    private class ListNode
    {
        T data;
        ListNode link;

        public ListNode(T aData, ListNode aLink)
        {
            data = aData;
            link = aLink;
        }
    }

    private ListNode head;
    private ListNode current;
    private ListNode previous;
    private int size;

    public GenLL()
    {
        head = current = previous = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    public void add(T aData)
    {
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(aData, null);
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = current = newNode;
            this.size = 1;
            return;
        }
        ListNode temp = head;
        while (temp.link != null)
        {
            temp = temp.link;
        }
            
        temp.link = newNode;
        this.size++;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        ListNode temp = head;
        while (temp != null)
        {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp = temp.link;
        }
    }

    public void addAfterCurrent(T aData)
    {
        if (current == null)
            return;

        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(aData, current.link);
        current.link = newNode;
        this.size++;
    }

    public T getCurrent()
    {
        if(current == null)
            return null;

        return current.data;
    }

    public void setCurrent(T aData)
    {
        if(aData == null || current == null)
            return;

        current.data = aData;
    }

    public void gotoNext()
    {
        if(current == null)
            return;

        previous = current;
        current = current.link;
    }

    public void reset()
    {
        current = head;
        previous = null; 
    }

    public boolean hasMore()
    {
        return current != null;
    }
    
    public void removeCurrent()
    {
        if (current == head)
        {
            head = head.link;
            current = head;
        }
        else
        {
            previous.link = current.link;
            current = current.link;
        }

        if (this.size > 0)
            size--;
    }

    public int getSize()
    {
        return this.size;
    }

    public T getAt(int index)
    {
        if(index < 0 || index >= size)
            return null;
        ListNode temp = head;
        for(int i=0;i<index;i++)
            temp = temp.link;
        return temp.data;
    }

    public void setAt(int index, T aData)
    {
        if(index < 0 || index >= size || aData == null)
            return;

        ListNode temp = head;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            temp = temp.link;
        temp.data = aData;
        
    }

    public T search() throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Search: ");
        String query = keyboard.nextLine();

        ListNode temp = head;

        while(!temp.equals(query))
            temp = temp.link;

        return temp.data;

        //plus some sort of print function to display the result in the console
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `regex` for every node's content, if the data type is `string` apply it if it is of some other datatype convert it into `string` if possible, else throw some exceptions.